# c- assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast

Tags: c, pointers, casting, warnings, block

I got a warning:

```
assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast.
```

The line that triggers the warning is:

```
nev[i][0]="";
```

The `nev` variable is a 2 dimension char block(please don't ask why, I don't know).

Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: If `nev` is a 2-dimensional array of `char`, then `nev[i][0]` is a `char`. But `""` is an array of `char`, not a `char`.

Comment: `nev[i][0]="";` --> `nev[i][0]=0;`

Comment: I accidentally closed it with wrong question. Reopened it.

Comment: Ah, I get it! :) Thanks guys!

Comment: `""` represents an array of `char`, yes, but furthermore, like any array it is converted to a pointer to its first element when evaluated.  That's where the pointer comes from.

Comment: Also, keep in mind that `""` is an empty string (containing only the terminating '\0'), but there is no empty character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `nev` is a 2-dimensional array of `char`, then `nev[i][0]` is a `char`. But `""` is an array of `char`, not a `char`.
                    – Barmar

`nev[i][0]="";` --> `nev[i][0]=0;`
                    – BLUEPIXY